# Change the login form in secure social

Tags: scala, authentication, playframework, securesocial

i'm writing a play 2.3 application using secure social.
I've customize my login form:

```
@(loginForm: Form[(String,String)], errorMsg: Option[String] = None)(implicit request: RequestHeader, lang: Lang, env:securesocial.core.RuntimeEnvironment[_])
@import securesocial.core.providers.UsernamePasswordProvider.UsernamePassword

@main(Messages("securesocial.login.title"))(null) {
    <div class="login">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>@Messages("securesocial.login.title")</h1>
        </div>

     @errorMsg.map { msg =>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                @Messages(msg)
            </div>
        }

     @request.flash.get("success").map { msg =>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                @msg
            </div>
        }

    @request.flash.get("error").map { msg =>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            @msg
        </div>
    }

    @defining( env.providers.values.filter( _.id != UsernamePassword) ) { externalProviders =>

        @env.providers.get(UsernamePassword).map { up =>
            <div class="clearfix">
                @if( externalProviders.size > 0 ) {
                    <p>@Messages("securesocial.login.useEmailAndPassword")</p>
                } else {
                    <p>@Messages("securesocial.login.useEmailAndPasswordOnly")</p>
                }

                @securesocial.views.html.provider("userpass", Some(loginForm))
            </div>
        }
    }

    </div>
}
```

But when the view is display i see "Did you forget your password? If you don't have an account with us yet you can sign up here".
But i don't want it, in my application the user get the credentials from the administrator, he can't signup and change the password. how can i do that?

Furthemore i don't want to import all the secure social routes, but only the routes needed for the login action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the [source](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/views/provider.scala.html#L47) of the `securesocial.views.html.provider` template which is imported in your customized login page you will see that password recovery information is defined there:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <p><a href="@env.routes.resetPasswordUrl">@Messages("securesocial.login.forgotPassword") </a></p>
</div>
```

All you need to do is to customize this part of a view as well. Create an another template based on the original SecureSocial view and remove parts that are not required for you.

If you want to allow only login and logout actions simply omit other route definitions and don't put them in your route file. You need only:

```
GET     /login                      securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login
GET     /logout                     securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.logout
```

and providers entry points:

```
GET     /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticate(provider)
POST    /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticateByPost(provider)
GET     /not-authorized             securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.notAuthorized
```

If you want to allow your user to change a password after login you should consider using build-in actions:

```
GET     /password                   securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.page
POST    /password                   securesocial.controllers.PasswordChange.handlePasswordChange
```